# jquery remove span in breadcrumb

Tags: jquery

I would like to remove some elements of a breadcrumb.
Essentialy **> Pages > default**
What is the best way to remove those accross the site with jQuery ?

Home > Agenda **> Pages > default**

The result would be Home > Agenda

```
<div class="breadcrumb">    
<span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderTeqBreadcrumb_siteMapPath">
    <span><a href="/" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">Home</a></span>
    <span> &gt; </span>
    <span><a href="/Agenda" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">Agenda</a></span>
    <span> &gt; </span>
    <span><a href="/Agenda/_layouts/listform.aspx?ListId=%7BA82B0240%2D8259%2D4F79%2DA710%2D66E4BA436A53%7D&amp;PageType=0" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">Pages</a></span>
    <span> &gt; </span>
    <span><a href="/Agenda/Pages/default.aspx" class="current">default</a></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Home  > All Meetings **> Pages > default**

the result would be Home  > All Meetings

```
<div class="breadcrumb">    
<span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderTeqBreadcrumb_siteMapPath"><span>
    <a href="/" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">Home</a></span>
    <span> &gt; </span>
    <span><a href="/AllMeetings" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">All Meetings</a></span>
    <span> &gt; </span>
    <span><a href="/AllMeetings/_layouts/listform.aspx?ListId=%7B9A69EF7E%2D31FF%2D49C7%2DA191%2D5CE2240E7ABC%7D&amp;PageType=0" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">Pages</a></span>
    <span> &gt; </span>
    <span><a href="/AllMeetings/Pages/default.aspx" class="current">default</a></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

and in some cases i have

Home > All Meetings > Pages > Functional Meetings

where i would like to remove **> Pages**

The result would be

Les Embiez 2012 > All Meetings > Functional Meetings

```
<div class="breadcrumb">    
<span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderTeqBreadcrumb_siteMapPath">
    <span><a href="/" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">Home</a></span>
    <span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/AllMeetings" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">All Meetings</a></span>
    <span> &gt; </span><span><a href="/AllMeetings/_layouts/listform.aspx?ListId=%7B9A69EF7E%2D31FF%2D49C7%2DA191%2D5CE2240E7ABC%7D&amp;PageType=0" class="ms-sitemapdirectional">Pages</a></span>
    <span> &gt; </span>
    <span><a href="/AllMeetings/Pages/Functional%20Meetings.aspx" class="current">Functional Meetings</a></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I am currently using the following JQuery to achieve this:

```
var url = location.pathname;
        if (url.indexOf('/Pages/default.aspx') >= 0) {
            $(".breadcrumb span").slice(-4).remove()
        }
        else {
            $(".breadcrumb span a:contains('Pages'),.breadcrumb span a:contains('default')").remove();
            $(".breadcrumb span:contains('>')").last().remove();
        }
```

Comment: I did not down-vote this question and it is a shame that the person who did chose not to leave their reason. I would suspect this may be because you have not shown that you have researched the problem or tried anything yourself. What have you tried already?

Comment: :) yes i have. i just looking a the best option. asking the community for advice :)

Comment: Ok, well the best thing to do is show the code you have already and then people can offer advice on how it could be improved. The worst thing about asking "the best way to things" is that is often open to opinion. So it could be better to ask, how could I improve this...

Comment: didn't downvote either.  it is a good question and although a quick google gives a number of ways to do this, it doesn't hurt to ask it.  I am curious why you want to programmatically remove the spans rather than updating the html without the spans.

Comment: Also, not to try and move this question away from Stack Overflow, but Stack Exchange have a code review site (currently in Beta) which you might find useful when looking for ways to improve your code:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i had $(".teq-breadcrumb a:contains('Pages')" ).remove()
$(".teq-breadcrumb a:contains('default')" ).remove()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = location.pathname;
        if (url.indexOf('/Pages/default.aspx') >= 0) {
            $(".breadcrumb span").slice(-4).remove()
        }
        else {
            $(".breadcrumb span a:contains('Pages'),.breadcrumb span a:contains('default')").remove();
            $(".breadcrumb span:contains('>')").last().remove();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an id or class to the span tag which identifies it?
Then you can use

```
$('.spanBCPages').remove();
$('.spanBCDefault').remove();
```

or similar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("span a").filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).text() == "Pages";
}).parent().prev().nextAll("span").remove();
```